# AttributeError: 'exactInputSingle' object has no attribute 'buildTransaction'

Tags: uniswap, web3.py, python, uniswapv3, router

I want to swap tokenA to tokenB. Thequestion heppened:

```
  File "E:\Code\pythonProject\infura_API_test\3_swap_by_web3_py.py", line 76, in <module>
    tx_swap = router.functions.exactInputSingle(params).buildTransaction(\
AttributeError: 'exactInputSingle' object has no attribute 'buildTransaction'
```

This is source code：

```py
import os
import json
import time

from dotenv import load_dotenv
from web3 import Web3

# ===============================================
# load .env
tmp = load_dotenv("./.env")
print("load env: ", tmp)

# 
PRIVATE_KEY = os.getenv("PRIVATE_KEY")
MY_ADDRESS = os.getenv("MY_ADDRESS")

# 
GETH = os.getenv("GETH")     # g_eth
UNI = os.getenv("UNI")      # uniswap
WETH = os.getenv("WETH")     # WETH

#
main = os.getenv("main")
goerli = os.getenv("goerli")
sepolia = os.getenv("sepolia")

#
FACTORY_ADDRESS = "0x1F98431c8aD98523631AE4a59f267346ea31F984"
QUOTER_ADDRESS = "0xb27308f9F90D607463bb33eA1BeBb41C27CE5AB6"
SWAP_ROUTER_ADDRESS = "0xE592427A0AEce92De3Edee1F18E0157C05861564"

#
with open("ABIs/SwapRouter.json", "r") as f:
    swap_router_abi = json.loads(f.read())

with open("ABIs/Quoter.json", "r") as f:
    quoter_abi = json.loads(f.read())

# ===============================================
w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(goerli))
print("connect to w3: ", w3.is_connected())

router = w3.eth.contract(address=SWAP_ROUTER_ADDRESS, abi=swap_router_abi)
quoter = w3.eth.contract(address=QUOTER_ADDRESS, abi=quoter_abi)

# pool fee is one of  500 (0.05%), 3000 (0.30%), 100000 (1%).
pool_fee = 500
# amount you want to swap
amount = w3.to_wei("0.0001", "ether")

# estimate output amount
sqrtPriceLimitX96 = 0   # this value is ignored if it is set to 0.
estimated_amount_out = quoter.functions.quoteExactInputSingle(WETH, UNI, pool_fee, amount, sqrtPriceLimitX96).call()

input("You will get {} UNI TOKENS. Press any key to coutinue.".format(w3.from_wei(estimated_amount_out, "ether")))

# swap dai to weth
deadline = int(time.time() + 60*10)     # Set deadline as 10 min.
amountOutMinimum = int(0*0.99)          # Set slippage as 1%.
sqrtPriceLimitX96 = 0                   # this value is ignored if it is set to 0.
nonce = w3.eth.get_transaction_count(MY_ADDRESS)
params = [WETH, UNI, pool_fee, MY_ADDRESS, deadline, amount, amountOutMinimum, sqrtPriceLimitX96]

tx_swap = router.functions.exactInputSingle(params).buildTransaction({
    'chainId': 5,
    'type': 2,
    'gas': 10**6,
    'maxFeePerGas': w3.to_wei('100', 'gwei'),
    'nonce': nonce + 1,
})

#
signed_tx_swap = w3.eth.account.sign_transaction(tx_swap, private_key=PRIVATE_KEY)
#
result = w3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_tx_swap.rawTransaction)
print(result.hex())
```

Answer (score 0):

I get the answer form github:

'in v6, it's snaked cased as build_transaction()'

from:https://github.com/ethereum/web3.py/issues/1340